# How to convert unsigned short to string in C?

Tags: c

I am not familiar to C programming and used to casting some variables to string by `ToString()` in C#.

But now I need to write a similar function in C for some embedded Linux system.

What is the most general way to do that?

For example：

```
unsigned short a = 1234;
char* a_string = malloc(5);

char* ToString(unsigned short v)
{
    char* str
    ...
    ...
    return str;
}

int main()
{
    a_string = ToString(a);
}
// result : a_string[0] = '1',  a_string[1] = '2', a_string[2] = '3', a_string[3] = '4', a_string[4] = '\0'
```

I would appreciate some hint or direction.

Comment: See `sprintf` and friends.

Comment: `char* a_string = malloc(5);` followed by `a_string = ToString(a);` is a potential memory leak. Not to mention that you should generally never use global variables.

Comment: Yeah, `sprintf()` (well, `snprintf()` to be safe!) is the most generic way.

Comment: To solve your problems visit - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-the-best-way-in-c-to-convert-a-number-to-a-string/

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: OP says he's doing embedded work. Globals certainly have their use in that setting.

Comment: @gspr I said *generally*, not always. And in the code shown it's not suitable at all. And `malloc` is *generally* discouraged in embedded work. ;)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: To be fair, you said *generally never*, whatever that might mean ;-)   But let's not get off topic here. We agree that globals should not be used for what OP is trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 2):

```
char * a_string = malloc(128);
snprintf(a_string, 128, "%u", a);
```

See the [man pages for printf(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) for more information.

In short, `printf` and friends take a [format string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string) that can contain a bunch of placeholders that signify the formatting of the arguments to follow. In the above, we just use `%u`, which is the format placeholder for an `unsigned int`. With `sprintf` we write the result to the buffer in the first argument (`a_string`) instead of to standard output.

The `snprintf` variant is for safety, to guarantee that we do not write more than the buffer size (here `128`, but you should think about what you want in general). Since C strings are null-terminated, it does not matter that we don't use all of the buffer size. Code interpreting `a_string` as a string will not consider more of the buffer than what was written by `snprintf`.

Missing from this answer is error handling: if `snprintf` returns a value of at least the size argument (here `128`), then it had to truncate its output. If it returns negative, an error occurred. You'll want to deal with these cases.

PS: If you're in an embedded setting, and you know the size of the output string at compile time (which you probably know since you know the size of `unsigned short`), you'll probably want to use an array on the stack for the string buffer instead of heap allocating it.

Comment: One can use `snprintf` to get the length of the generated string, so it's possible to allocate only the amount needed.

Comment: That is a very good point!